# Why does pallet-scheduler retain agendas with unavailable preimages

Tags: pallet-scheduler

If I'm reading the code of pallet-scheduler correctly, if the preimage of an agenda is not available, then the agenda remains in storage, but `IncompleteSince` is not updated, which means that the agenda will remain in storage without any chance of executing the scheduled call later, even if the preimage is supplied. According to this test, this is expected behavior: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/713e34ae960d122519093c9015f64c4afd74aa53/frame/scheduler/src/tests.rs#L1135-L1199

But why isn't the agenda just removed?

Comment: This was introduced in https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11649.

Comment: I remember there was automatic rescheduling logic in the code at one point and it would move the agenda to some block in the future. Updating the `IncompleteSince` here is not right AFAIK. Maybe that automatic re-scheduling logic was removed before we merged it...

Comment: "Updating the `IncompleteSince` here is not right AFAIK." By "here" you mean the sitatuion of an unavailable preimage? Yeah, absolutely, setting `IncompleteSince` in this situation seems like a bad idea. But why is the agenda kept around?

Comment: It's basically this one line: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0cbea5805e0f4edcf8a3a70135b4d8eabc2db06f/frame/scheduler/src/lib.rs#L1044. Why do we check for `dropped > 0`?